# Tortoise SVN - menu items are not showing up

Tags: windows, svn, tortoisesvn

I unchecked commit in settings, but still it is not coming in context menu. Not only commit , anything is not coming in context menu except SVN checkout,SVN Repo-browser,SVN import,SVN export,SVN create repository. Screen shots are below.
[image]
[image]

I have tried with "TortoiseSVN-1.10.5.28651-x64-svn-1.10.6", and "TortoiseSVN-1.13.1.28686-x64-svn-1.13.0". Both are having same issues. Can anybody say how to solve this?
Note: I am using Windows 10 - pro, 64 bit.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález It worked . Give this comment as answer so that I can vote it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are the menu entries you get in arbitrary directories, i.e. those that aren't inside Subversion working copies. Your path names suggests you have some source code you've downloaded from the internet, not a Subversion working copy you've checked out.